# Rails new command

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just downloaded Ruby on Rails through [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org). I've seen on a tutorial that to start a new project, I had to tap `rails new` + the name of my new app on the terminal. But when I do that, I've got an error :

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/744rk.png)

**The specified path was not found**

Does anyone have an idea to help me ?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that the `rails` command is available in your PATH...I think the problem is not `rails new`, but rather the fact that your shell does not know where to find the `rails` command.

Comment: Okay, I modified the paths on the `rails.bat` file to the corrects paths (due to RailsInstaller) and saved it. Now it works. Thanks you !